# Flutter Firebase: Getting snapshot's data in flutter not working

Tags: firebase, flutter, stream-builder

I'm trying to get the length for ListViewBuilder ItemCount with snapshot.data.docs.length but I get the error:
"The getter 'docs' isn't defined for the class 'Object'."

Here is my code:

```
StreamBuilder<Object>(
                stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('recipe').doc(_user).collection('Food').snapshots(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  return ListView.builder(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return RecipeCards(
                        
                      );
                    },
                  );
                }
              ),
```

Comment: Can you assure that you get the data with your FirebaseFirestore call? Is the structure given?

Comment: I'm new to Firebase, how can I check if i get data with the FirebaseFirestore call?

Comment: I tried adding: if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        print('has data');
                      }
                      if (snapshot.hasError) {
                        print('has error');
                      }. I got 'has data'.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by using:

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>
```

Instead of:

```
StreamBuilder<Object>
```